# Google App Engine GoogleCredential getApplicationDefault

Tags: google-app-engine, oauth

I am trying to use GoogleCredential getApplicationDefault() to get access to the app engine default service account which I have already created using app engine dashboard. The code is as shown below.

```
    try{
        GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.getApplicationDefault();
        if (credential.createScopedRequired()){
            ArrayList<String> scope = new ArrayList<String>();
            scope.add("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_write");
            GoogleCredential scopedCredential = credential.createScoped(scope);
            scopedCredential.refreshToken();
            return scopedCredential.getAccessToken();
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
        entityException = new Entity(Constants.ENTITY_EXCEPTION);
        entityException.setProperty("Exception",ex.getMessage());
        datastore.put(entityException);
    }
    return "";
```

When scopedCredential.refreshToken() is called an exception happens with the message accounts.google.com

Also when I call scopedCredential.getServiceAccountId() and scopedCredential.getServiceAccountPrivateKeyId() I am getting the correct values of the default app engine service account.

Can anyone please help me with this.

Guys,

Can someone help me? I tried adding a new service account, created a p12 file instead of json etc. nothing seems to work. I hv no idea where I m going wrong. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Hey all I figured it out myself. I specified runtime as java8 and that was causing all the problems. guess these work only on java7 runtime. thanks.